# Не создается сервис в Symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony3

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно создать сервис в symfony 3.4.  Вроде все делается по мануалам, а все равно вылетает  **Uncaught PHP ExceptionSymfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: "You have requested a non-existent service "obb.naming"**

Контроллер:

```
    namespace Ost\BlogBundle\Controller;

    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

    class TestController extends Controller
    {
        public function heyAction()
        {
            $name= 'qqqq';
            $naming = $this->get("obb.naming");
            $naming->setName($name);
            return $this->render("Test/hey.html.twig",array('message'=>$naming->getName()));
        }
    }
```

Класс который хочу сделать сервисом:

```
namespace Ost\BlogBundle\Services;

class Naming
{
    private $name;

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Файл services.yml (src/Ost/BlogBundle/Resourses/config/):

```
obb.naming:
      class: Ost\BlogBundle\Services\Naming
```

Файл config.yml (app/config/):

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: "@OstBlogBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
```

С аргументами пробовал, в конструктор передавать пробовал (со ссылкой на другой сервис), и вызывать в конструкторе через контейнер пробовал ($this->container->get("obb.naming")) ... может чего не доглядел. Помогите, плиз

Comment: 1. В каком коружении исполняется код? Если не dev, сбросьте кеш.

Comment: 2. По-умолчанию сервисы приватны и попытка достать их прямо из контейнера в контроллере не закончится успехом. Добавьте в описание сервиса public: true, а лучше внедряйте его зависимостью.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Решил проблему. Мой косяк был. Нужно было сделать сервисом класс в конструктор которого нужно было пробросить экземпляр класса. Обращение через метод get к сервису из контейнера, действительно не то)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:
В services.yml объявляете сервис следующим образом:

```
AppBundle\Service\FileManager:
    arguments:
        $targetDirectory: '%files_directory%'
```

Далее в контроллере:

```
public function editAction(FileManager $fileManager)
{
    //сервис доступен как переменная
}
```

Вообще должно работать и без объявления в services.yml. Просто создаете класс и передаете его как параметр в нужный action метод.